# Canot send mail with mailgun smtp using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mailgun

I'm trying to send an email using codeigniter email library and mailgun smtp.
The smtp settings are configured corectly and i don't know what could be the problem....

here is the php code:

```
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
$config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.mailgun.org';
$config['smtp_port'] = 25;
$config['smtp_user'] = 'user@user.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'thepasswordconfiguredinmailgun';
$config['smtp_timeout'] = '4';
$config['crlf'] = '\n';
$config['newline'] = '\r\n';

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->clear(TRUE);
$this->email->from('office@test.com', 'FromName');
$this->email->to('myemail@yahoo.com');

$this->email->subject('Subiect de test');
$this->email->message('Testez sa vad daca merge si daca pot sa trimit. Daca nu pot de ce nu pot ?');

$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

I've got the following errors:

```
The following SMTP error was encountered: 110 Connection timed out
Unable to send data: AUTH LOGIN
Failed to send AUTH LOGIN command. Error:
Unable to send data: MAIL FROM:

from: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: RCPT TO:

to: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: DATA

data: 

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send data: User-Agent: CodeIgniter Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 10:19:19 +0300 From: "PADigest" Return-Path: To: test123@yahoo.com Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Subiect_de_test?= Reply-To: "office@padiads.ro" X-Sender: office@padigest.ro X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority: 3 (Normal) Message-ID: <57357ff767c94@padiads.ro> Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_57357ff767d02" This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application may not support this format. --B_ALT_57357ff767d02 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit Testez sa vad daca merge si daca pot sa trimit. Daca nu pot de ce nu pot ? --B_ALT_57357ff767d02 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable Testez sa vad daca merge si daca pot sa trimit. Daca nu pot de ce nu pot ? --B_ALT_57357ff767d02--
Unable to send data: .

The following SMTP error was encountered:
Unable to send email using PHP SMTP. Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 10:19:19 +0300
From: "PADigest" <office@padiast.ro>
Return-Path: <office@padiasr.ro>
To: test124@yahoo.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Subiect_de_test?=
Reply-To: "office@padiast.ro" <office@padiast.ro>
X-Sender: office@padiast.ro
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <57357ff767c94@padigest.ro>
Mime-Version: 1.0


Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_57357ff767d02"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_57357ff767d02
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Testez sa vad daca merge si daca pot sa trimit. Daca nu pot de ce nu pot ?


--B_ALT_57357ff767d02
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Testez sa vad daca merge si daca pot sa trimit. Daca nu pot de ce nu pot ?

--B_ALT_57357ff767d02--
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking [Mailgun's documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/faqs.html#i-am-getting-timeouts-when-connecting-via-smtp-why):

Most often, this is caused by internet service providers (“ISP”) blocking port #25. This tends to happen if you are using a residential ISP.

To check this, try running telnet in command line:

```
telnet smtp.mailgun.org 25
```

If port 25 is not blocked, you should see something like this:

```
Trying 174.37.214.195...
Connected to mxa.mailgun.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mxa.mailgun.org (Mailgun)
```

If you don’t see this, then you are being blocked. There are a couple workarounds:

1. Send using the HTTP API
2. Try using port #587 or #2525

Comment: I dont think the port is blocked. If i try to use localhost as a smtp server, mail sends. I dont have access on terminal since i'm on shared hosting, but i sent an email @ hosting provider to write the command in console.

Comment: @florin Have you tried other ports such as 2525 as documentation says?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my shared hosting provider. Seams that they dont accept connections to external smtp mail providers. However I will accept sotoz answer as I will send them using http api !